# Elastic single word search issue

Tags: elasticsearch

Following sample data, I've inserted in my index...

```
"name":"Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Silver", "price":"100"
"name":"Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Gold", "price":"200"
"name":"Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Space Gray", "price":"300"
"name":"iPhone 8", "price":"70000"
"name":"iPhone 8 Plus", "price":"80000"
"name":"iPhone X", "price":"100000"
"name":"iPhone 8 Case, Black color", "price":"500"
"name":"iPhone battery charger", "price":"1000"
```

Index Mapping

```
{
  "shopfront": {
    "mappings": {
      "products": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "price": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I'm running following query...

```
POST shopfront/products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "iphone"
    }
  }
}
```

the result I'm getting is

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 8,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "shopfront",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Space Gray",
          "price": "300"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "shopfront",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 0.19566216,
        "_source": {
          "name": "iPhone 8 Case, Black color",
          "price": "500"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "shopfront",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "name": "iPhone 8 Plus",
          "price": "80000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "shopfront",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "8",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "name": "iPhone battery charger",
          "price": "1000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "shopfront",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.17068404,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Silver",
          "price": "100"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "shopfront",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.16403349,
        "_source": {
          "name": "iPhone 8",
          "price": "70000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "shopfront",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 0.16403349,
        "_source": {
          "name": "iPhone X",
          "price": "100000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "shopfront",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.097333126,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Gold",
          "price": "200"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I want is all "iPhone" should come on top & rest of things should come in bottom of search list.

Ex:

```
iPhone 8
iPhone 8 Plus
iPhone X
iPhone 8 Case, Black color
iPhone battery charger
Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Silver
Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Gold
Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Space Gray
```

"match_phrase_prefix" is also doing any help. Any idea, how to handl esuch situation?

Comment: you can loop through the results, check the first word and match it to your query and sort accordingly. just a workaround.

Comment: Yeah, that I can do as a last option. But, now I'm looking some solution from the elastic point of view. I really feel there might've any easy solution to do this in Elastic itself as it is a very basic kind of requirement from the search point of view.

Comment: POST shopfront/products/_search?`explain=true` will help you understand the scoring.

Comment: Please make sure that the index has only one shard since you have so few documents. Or else run your query with param: `?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch`.
You should get the results in the right order with this. 
https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean query with a regexp should clause on the `name.keyword` field to boost the scores for the entries that start with iPhone.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Note that all elasticsearch regex queries are anchored:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators

so doing `iphone.*` will always match only to the start of the line and there is no need for a `^` to match to the front.  The overall query would then look like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "should" : {
                "regexp" : {
                    "name.keyword" : "i[pP]hone [0-9X]( Plus)?"
                }
            },
            "must" : {
                 "match" : {
                     "name" : "iphone"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By using ```name.keyword``` I'm getting ```iPhone battery charger``` in second place just after ```iPhone 8 Plus```. Which is not in the order I want. I want the response should be in following order ```iPhone 8,iPhone 8 Plus,iPhone X,iPhone 8 Case, Black color,iPhone battery charger,Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Silver,Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Gold,Apple silicon cases for iPhone 6S Space Gray```

Comment: Hmm, I thought we were just trying to get any that started with iPhone. That's fine though, just need to tweak the regex to be more specific. I think say iPhone, followed by a number or X then the end of the string or plus will work so have edited the above to state this.

Comment: The above ```regex``` solution will only work for ```iphone```.  But, I was looking for some generic solution which will work in all cases(different kind of products from different brands).

Comment: What is the thing that makes the "phone" product unique? You should be able to adjust the regex to cover other cases with an array of regexp queries in the should or if there are too many different cases having a "product type" : "phone" field would be better

Comment: Ok. I think I got it... what you wanted to say. Although, this is not the complete solution of my problem... it's sure guiding me in the right direction. So, I'm accepting this answer. Thanks for your help.